# Solving Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a slider in which I'm rendering images and video, but sometimes `video` is empty so on specific rendered items I'm getting.

```
Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4028:2 in createTextInstance
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14494:37 in completeWork
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
    in AdContextProvider (at App.js:30)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:166:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
- node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:24 in serializeLogDataAsync$
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

my custom component

```
<ScrollView flex={1} backgroundColor="#eee">
      <Slider
        items={[...images, video]}
        keyExtractor={(t) => t}
        renderItem={(t, { width, height, index }) => (
          <Box backgroundColor="white" padding={25}>
            {index === images.length && (
              <Video
                source={{ uri: video }}
                rate={1.0}
                volume={1.0}
                isMuted={false}
                resizeMode="cover"
                useNativeControls={true}
                isLooping
                style={{
                  width: width - 50,
                  height: height - 50,
                }}
              />
            )}
            {index !== images.length && (
              <Image
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={{ uri: t }}
                style={{ 
                  width: width - 50,
                  height: height - 50,
                }}
              />
            )}
          </Box>
        )}
      />
```

so what is the right way of fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simplest solution is adding another and condition

```
<ScrollView flex={1} backgroundColor="#eee">
  <Slider
    items={[...images, video]}
    keyExtractor={(t) => t}
    renderItem={(t, { width, height, index }) => (
      <Box backgroundColor="white" padding={25}>
        {index === images.length && video !== null && (
          <Video
            source={{ uri: video }}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={false}
            resizeMode="cover"
            useNativeControls={true}
            isLooping
            style={{
              width: width - 50,
              height: height - 50,
            }}
          />
        )}
        {index !== images.length && (
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{ uri: t }}
            style={{ 
              width: width - 50,
              height: height - 50,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Box>
    )}
  />
```

Comment: yes it is, but surprisingly it's not working for some reason

Comment: maybe video !== "" solve it, as video may not be null but empty

Comment: it was something else, but your answer is the right way of doing it so will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, honestly I don't know the types from your variables but it happens when you don't use a boolean in this kind of conditions

```
            {index !== images.length && (
              <Image
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={{ uri: t }}
                style={{ 
                  width: width - 50,
                  height: height - 50,
                }}
              />
            )}
```

In this manner, try to use the double negation (!!) to get the boolean value from the variable. For example:

```
{!!someText && <Component />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator(!) instead of short circuit operator(&&). short circuit operator may cause text volation error on non boolean data types.

## example

```
<ScrollView flex={1} backgroundColor="#eee">
  <Slider
    items={[...images, video]}
    keyExtractor={(t) => t}
    renderItem={(t, { width, height, index }) => (
      <Box backgroundColor="white" padding={25}>
        {index === images.length ? (
          <Image
            resizeMode="contain"
            source={{ uri: t }}
            style={{ 
              width: width - 50,
              height: height - 50,
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Video
            source={{ uri: video }}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={false}
            resizeMode="cover"
            useNativeControls={true}
            isLooping
            style={{
              width: width - 50,
              height: height - 50,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Box>
    )}
  />
```